# event listener .change doesn't respond

Tags: jquery

i have an input box in which a user type an e-mail. If the input is != 0, i want my script to keep a button in my DOM disabled. However, if it change and the value becomes > 0, i want it to enable my button.

Unfortunately nothing happens.

This is what i have so far:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#input1").change(function(){
            if($(this).val().length > 0){
                $("#emailSignup").prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else{
                $("#emailSignup").prop('disabled', true);
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Email, new { id="input1", Class = "form-control", Style = "display:inline-block; max-width:200px", Placeholder="Example@Example.com", type="email"})
<button disabled type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="display:inline-block" id="emailSignup">Tilmeld</button>
```

Comment: is the input dynamically added?if so use event deledation

Comment: it is dynamically added yes, no postback

Comment: Have you look at console log? Maybe there's some error message there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use on key up instead maybe:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js">
    $(document).on('keyup', '#input1', function() {
        if($(this).val().length > 0){
            $("#emailSignup").removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $("#emailSignup").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this script? thanks.
You have to define the variable then test the function.

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Email, new { id="input1", Class = "form-control", Style = "display:inline-block; max-width:200px", Placeholder="Example@Example.com", type="email"})
<button disabled="disabled" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="display:inline-block" id="emailSignup">Tilmeld</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.emailSignup').attr('disabled',true);
    $('#message').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length !=0)
            $('.emailSignup').attr('disabled', false);            
        else
            $('.emailSignup').attr('disabled',true);
    })
});
```

Comment: Nothing should be different in this. - it doesn't work, unfortunately

Comment: @JeppeChristensen, could you share your HTML code for   #input1 ?

Comment: @JeppeChristensen could you try because i see your button disabled in html is not defined.